# Oracle Db 11g trigger syntax

Tags: c#, oracle, visual-studio

I try create trigger in Oracle DB 11g but no success.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER mytable_JOBUPD 
AFTER UPDATE OF jedan, trip ON mytable 
FOR EACH ROW 
BEGIN 
ADD_mytable_JOB ( :old.jedan, :old.trip, 'update', sysdate);
END mytable_JOBUPD;​
```

this error is dispatched:

```
Compilation failed,line 1 (18:23:50)
```

PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "," when expecting one of the following: in out ... long double ref char time timestamp interval date binary national character nchar Compilation failed,line 3 (18:23:50)
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "BEGIN" when expecting one of the following: not null of nan infinite dangling a empty Compilation failed,line 5 (18:23:50)
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following: , ; return returning

So everrything is problem but what? My columns type in database are ok but I still got this error?

Answer (score 0):

Replace "FOR EACH ROW" with this:

```
REFERENCING OLD AS old NEW AS new FOR EACH ROW
```

I have a few similar triggers in place in 11g that follow this same syntax.

Edit: you may also need a declare after that, before the begin.  If not declaring any variables, I do this:

```
DECLARE
    -- no variables
BEGIN
  --Code
```

Edit 2:

Your syntax in the example post is otherwise correct.  Those errors do seem to indicate a missing (or extra) quote, comma, or semicolon.